# Ionic / ui router - How to avoid history update on state change

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

When i change the state using `$state.go`, the history change is automagically updated. i would like being able to change  a state avoinding the registration of this change in the history.

I have looked at `$ionicHistory` but i couldn't find my happiness.

Answer (score 0):

I perform that using that `$ionicHistory` service : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableBack: true
});
```

Then you can normally do your `$state.go`

Comment: In fact, when i use it, I can't go back from my new state...
Assuming three states A->B->C, i just want to forgot B but being able to go back to A from B or C

Comment: therefore you need to use : goBack(-2) on the new state when press backBtn but your usecase does not seems to be handle yet with ionic